# How to avoid "()" when writing a decorator accepting optional arguments?

Tags: python, decorator

I've written this decorator to deprecate a function and (optionally) provide a callable as replacement

```
 def deprecated(repfun=None):
    """A decorator which can be used to mark functions as deprecated.
    Optional repfun is a callable that will be called with the same args
    as the decorated function.
    """
    def outer(fun):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            msg = "%s is deprecated" % fun.__name__
            if repfun is not None:
                msg += "; use %s instead" % (repfun.__name__)
            warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
            if repfun is not None:
                return repfun(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return fun(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return outer
```

Now, I can use my decorator as such:

```
@deprecated()
def foo():
    return 0
```

...or provide an optional argument:

```
@deprecated(some_function)
def foo():
    return 0
```

...but I don't know how to modify it so that I can omit parentheses:

```
@deprecated
def foo():
    return 0
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the argument to `deprecated()` is a function, there is no reliable way to determine if this is the function to be used as a replacement, or the function to be deprecated. Hence, there is no way to do what you want without changing it to take a string instead.

Comment: Or just split the function in two: `@deprecated` and `deprecated_by(some_func)`.